# Control/Limit user's thread usage in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, parallel-processing

Is it possible to control or limit a user's parallel thread usage in oracle?

Lets say, user `dev` is executing a `SELECT` query which is taking 32 parallel threads.

But, irrespective of the hints or table design, i want the query to run in single thread as with `/*NOPARALLEL*/` hint. This should happen to whatever DML transaction user `dev` does with the DB.

Is there any way i could achieve this?
I tried searching for an approach but couldn't reach anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

The only way we can limit a user's consumption of system resources is with a profile.  The CREATE PROFILE option provides a couple of options for limiting CPU usage, CPU_PER_SESSION and CPU_PER_CALL , but alas not number of CPUs.   [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_6010.htm#i2065930).

I would say that in the sort of environment where we would want to impose resource limits - i.e. a live one - the use of parallel query should either be left to the database through the PARALLEL_AUTOMATIC_TUNING parameter or be locked down by the PARALLEL hint on pre-canned queries only.